# QGIS Atlas Composer : Margin around feature not changing

Tags: print-composer, expression, atlas, qgis-2.14, qgis-2.18

I try to use an expression to set the margin around a feature in the atlas composer.

In documentation, it's explained that it's better to be a *double* but a *string* or *integer* is accepted as an input.

I use this expression that returns a *double*:

```
bounds_height( $geometry )/ bounds_height(  geometry( get_feature( 'allin1', 'id_ws_int', attribute(  @atlas_feature  ,  'id_ws_int' )  ))) *100+100
```

But nothing changes. Tried with `to_string` and `to_int` but same result.

Tested in *2.14.12* and *2.18.4*

No bug reported found.

Comment: Please check the expression results, perhaps using a label element in the composer. It should be e. g. `100.0` for 100 % margin.

Comment: Yes i checked with float and string concat %, 0.0 , 0,0 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your szenario in 2.18.4 and it works, see images below.

I choosed to have features in allin1 being smaller than in the atlas layer, so that different margins will have a visible impact. In the first picture the feature is 8.19 times higher than allin1, so your formula calculates to 919. In the second picture it is factor 2.72, result 372.

If allin1 features are bigger than the atlas features, results are between 100 and 200, which may make no eye-catching difference. So I guess your formula is not what you want and you didn't check the results.

I simplified `attribute(  @atlas_feature  ,  'id_ws_int' )` to `"id_ws_int"`; but both work.

[image: margin 919 %] [image: margin 372 %]

Comment: OK, i tested directly with numbers and it works. You are right it s because the zoom variation is not visible sometimes. Yhis mistakes comes from the percentage field is not up2date